# Add Image to layout on touch in android with respect to touch position

Tags: android

Where ever i touch on the screen with respect to x y position i need to add one image on that particular position.
I tried by implementing the ontouch listener but it is adding image to different position and many images are being appeared on many touch i want some thing like where ever i touch that same image should appear there
Please Help i am new to android working on project in a compnay

This is my activity code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wwcontainer);
    //Set On TouchListner to the Layout
            rl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.i("OnTouch", "On Touch View Group....");
                    int x = (int) event.getX();
                    int y = (int) event.getY();

                     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                     imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(x,y));
                     rl.addView(imageView);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

I know about drag and drop i dont want drag and drop instead i need touch any where there image should appear wrt touch position please help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had same request and this is what i done and it worked perfectly for me

```
final RelativeLayout rr = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rr);
    rr.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
                iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
                iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.gr1));
                ((ViewGroup) v).addView(iv);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This will place image to RelativeLayout where you touched starting coordinates from there. If you want to center new image where you touched RelativeLayout you need to calculate Height and Width of your image and change one line in my code to

```
lp.setMargins(x - yourImageWidth/2, y - yourImageHeight/2, 0, 0);
```

Comment: +1 for your answer. I would like to add something if you want to add image to the center of the user touch don't use x - yourImageWidth/2 instead of it use x - yourImageWidth and do same for the height also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) instead of RelativeLayout.

To add image at particular x,y location, you need AbsoluteLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what int value getX() and getY() returns i think it will return 0,0.

please use event.getRawX() & event.getRawX() for actual touch position. i hope it will help.